# Mongoose does not return properties that are empty objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

When I fetch records from MongoDB, fetched documents does not have properties that exist in database but that are empty objects. Is there some config that I should add to fetch also properties that are empty objects?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set [`minimize`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#minimize) to false.

Official example:

```
const schema = new Schema({ name: String, inventory: {} }, { minimize: false });
const Character = mongoose.model('Character', schema);

// will store `inventory` if empty
const sam = new Character({ name: 'Sam', inventory: {} });
await sam.save();
doc = await Character.findOne({ name: 'Sam' }).lean();
doc.inventory; // {}
```